# sql join with where clause

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using MYSQL I have 2 tables I would like to join and as the tables get larger I would like to know what would be a better way to query them.  The tables are used for a website that are storing pictures for various users.  Kind of like facebook.  First table is images table which has an Id and a source location field. and the other table is called user_images with a foreign key with the image id going to the image table.  The reason the tables are not put together is because multiple users can have the same picture and doing things this way will do away with redundancy.

Here is what my query would look like to get the source locations of all images for a particular user

```
SELECT i.source_location 
FROM user_images AS u
INNER JOIN images AS i
ON i.image_id = u.image_id
WHERE u.user_id = 'USER'
```

So my question is, would it be better to query it for faster results as shown below or does it not matter.

```
SELECT i.source_location
FROM
(SELECT image_id 
 FROM user_images
 WHERE user_id = 'USER') AS u
INNER JOIN images AS i
ON i.image_id = u.image_id
```

Basically I would think doing the where clause before the join would 
make for faster results because the db will have a shorter set to compare to because the join table will be alot smaller. I dont know if this is the right way of going through with this. **What would be the best way to go about this?**  If anyone else has any better ways of doing this please help me out because I see these tables getting rather large.

Comment: The MySQL query optimizer will run both in the same way.  In general, don't worry about performance until real people complain; by then, you'll have test data to verify possible solutions!

Comment: @Andomar -- you should post this as an answer because it is the answer to the question ;)

Comment: You [should not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) answer based on the asker; but based on the question... Practice more separation of concerns...

Answer (score -1):

Does your `images` table have a user_id field?

If so, just do the INNER JOIN `images` ON (i.image_id = u.image_id AND i.user_id = "USER")

Comment: You may also be able to do the join on u.user_id as well... I'm not in an active environment at the moment to test.

Comment: The question did say that multiple users can have the same image

Comment: I doubt it - he said "The reason the tables are not put together is because multiple users can have the same picture and doing things this way will do away with redundancy." so users <-> images is many-to-many, hence the user_images join table.

Comment: As `user_images` looks like the relation table between `users` and `images`, there should be no column like `user_id` in `images`. This would prevent a n:m relation.